# Why doesn't this __repr__ function return a string?

Tags: python, repr

```
class Person:
    greeting = 'Hello'
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.greeting

>>> Sam = Person()
>>> Sam.greeting
'Hello'
>>> Sam
Hello
```

I am having difficulty understanding why the __repr__ function returns self.greeting without quotes. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `__repr__` is not going to magically add quotes around the string, if you want quotes return `repr(self.greeting)`.

Comment: But if I explicitly call `Sam.__repr__()`, it returns `'Hello'` with the quotes. It seems to me as though the interactive prompt strips a layer of quotes, but I am inclined to think that's not the case.

Comment: String's `repr` representation looks like: `"'Hello'"` not `'Hello'`.

Comment: Have you tried to actually call the `__repr__` to see that it doesn't return a string? I guess not. Try `Sam.__repr__()` and see it return a string. Also `repr(Sam)` would return a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The REPL outputs the `repr` of the object.

If you say

```
>>> 'Hello'
```

The repr of "`Hello`" is displayed, which is "`'Hello'`"

Since you are returning `Hello` rather than `'Hello'` - that is what is displayed in the REPL

If you want the `Person.repr` to work like normal string `repr`, you can just call `repr` on `self.greeting`

```
>>> class Person:
...     greeting = 'Hello'
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return repr(self.greeting)
... 
>>> Sam = Person()
>>> Sam
'Hello'
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am still slightly confused, though. Aren't I returning `'Hello'` here? The expression self.greeting evaluates to `'Hello'`, and that's what \__repr__ should be returning to my understanding.

Comment: @user3052943, I think the quotes are confusing you. The greeting has 5 letters. If you return that as the repr, those 5 letters are exactly what gets displayed. You don't want extra quotes added round automatically because then it would be impossible to do the repr for an int, list, dict, etc.

Comment: Bare with me here.. my fundamental confusion basically comes down to this. The REPL should output the `repr` of the object, like you said. However, if i explicitly call the `repr` of `Person` by entering `Sam.__repr__()`, it returns the string in quotes. What is the difference between the automatic calling of the `repr` function and this explicit call?

Comment: @user3052943, If you call repr on Person, the return value is a string. The REPR calls repr on that string, so naturally the quotes get added at that stage

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's going on here, let's follow the "thought process" of the REPL:

Consider typing `Sam`:

1. Here's an object I want to display. It's a `Person` object.
2. I call `repr()` on the thing from step 1 and per the class definition, I get back the string `Hello` (five characters and no quotes).
3. To actually display the thing from step 2, I call `print()` on it.
4. I'm sure we can all agree that `print()` prints strings without syntactic quotes, so you don't get any.

Now consider `s.greeting`:

1. Here's an object I want to display. It's a `str` object.
2. I call `repr()` on the thing from step 1. Per `str`'s `__repr__()` method (which has logic to add quotes because it knows the *representation* of a string needs quotes), I get back the string `'Hello'` (seven characters, actual quotes included).
3. To actually display the thing from step 2, I call `print()` on it.
4. Since the string actually contains those quotes, they appear in the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `repr()` function, it returns `Person` object. But If you want to return string value, you can use `str()`

````
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        rep = 'Person(' + self.name + ',' + str(self.age) + ')'
        return rep

person = Person("John", 24)```
print(repr(person)) # Person(John,24)
````